# Custom email template with PDF attachment

Tags: magento-1.8, email-templates, pdf

I have implemented "full product lising" page with all the products in all categories (With approximately 200 products, varies on adding new products). This is in a tabular format which has only two columns:

1. Project Name
2. Price

And I have implemented dynamic generation of pdf with all these 200 products.

Now my requirement is to send this pdf in an email to the specified email address. How can i do with magento? Do i need to create new email template with pdf attachment?

Please suggest a best solution.

Comment: If you are creating a new module, have a look at below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374172/magento-custom-email-template-with-pdf-attachment

Comment: If your problem was solved, please select one of the answers as "accepted" to mark this question as solved. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
  $oEmailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('email_template');
  $oMail = $oEmailTemplate->getMail();
  $oAttachment = $oMail->createAttachment(
        file_get_contents($sPdfSrc),
        Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        basename($sPdfSrc)
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `Zend_Mail`.

https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/lib/Zend/Mail.php

You'll find it has everything you need to send mail from, say, your own controller or other module class.

Depending on what you're doing, you also could extend from a number of Magento classes that have mail sending methods. Have a look at `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` and you'll find there are some things to help integrate with Magento, but ultimately they just call `Zend_Mail`.

Answer (score 1):

You can see how did I do that in [this](https://github.com/buric/Comwrap_InvoiceEmails) extension. Check `app/code/local/Comwrap/InvoiceEmails/Model/Mailer.php` and `app/code/local/Comwrap/InvoiceEmails/Model/Observer.php`.